# How to detect if another daemon terminated

Tags: c, linux, process

I want to develop a daemon that will supervise another daemon. In case the other daemon is crashed or stoped for any reason then my daemon will restart it.

How I can detect if another (not child process) is stopped in C?

Comment: To clarify, when you say “stopped,” do you mean that the process has terminated, or do you mean that the daemon is SIGSTOP’d? I expect the former, but it makes a difference.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to *detect* if another process has terminated is if it is a child process of your supervisor.  In this case, you can call `wait` or `waitpid` or arrange to handle the `SIGCHLD` signal when the process exits.

This is fundamentally how a processor supervisor like `upstart` or `systemd` or `runit` or even legacy `init` works.

There are other ways that *sort of* work, but they are ultimately fragile and prone to problems.  For example, if you know the PID of the running process you can periodically signal it with `kill(pid, 0)` (an error indicates that the given pid is no longer runnign)...but there are two problems with this solution: PIDs can be recycled, so if the same PID is still active there is no guarantee it is actually the process in which you are interested.  Additionally, this requires periodically polling the running process, whereas calling `wait` or `waitpid` can be a blocking operation, which yields much simpler code.

Similarly, you can inspect the list of running processes in `/proc`, but this has pretty much the same problems as the previous solution.